# Showing suggestion box when typing in input box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get some sort of suggestion box in my application. The basic idea is that, when typing in an input box, 5 options show up below the input box with possible entries.

The problem I am facing is that, while there is nothing entered in the input box, the box which gives the possible suggestions already shows (see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbreg.png)). Of course, I only want it to show up when I enter something in the input box.

Any help?

Wout

CSS-code:

```
#suggestions {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 310px;
    top: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

JavaScript: --> option1, option2,... get a value in function "giveSuggestion()"

```
<form id = "suggestions">
    <input     type = "text" 
               id = "insertText" 
               autocomplete="off" 
               onkeyup = "if (event.keyCode == 13) {SearchAddress(option1.text)}
                          else {giveSuggestion()}"/>
    <option id = "option1" onclick = "searchAddress(option1.text)"></option>
    <option id = "option2" onclick = "searchAddress(option2.text)"></option>
    <option id = "option3" onclick = "searchAddress(option3.text)"></option>
    <option id = "option4" onclick = "searchAddress(option4.text)"></option>
    <option id = "option5" onclick = "searchAddress(option5.text)"></option>
</form>
```

Comment: Not that familiar with this, but shouldn't it be "oninput" instead of "onclick"? "Onclick" will be active as soon as the textbox is selected, whereas "oninput" will only be active when you type sth. into that textbox.

Comment: the "onclick" part is not the problem. That part is for when the options are actually visible and I want to select one of them

Comment: You don't have to build this by yourself, there are a lot of frameworks that does this for you already. Take a look at JqueryUI for instance (Or just google "input field with suggestions" and you will find a bunch of results) https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/gnph4evm/1/

I have added a new class:

```
.option{
   display:none;
}
```

and added it to all your options like:

```
  <option class="option" id = "option1" onmousedown = "searchAddress(option1.text)" >text1</option>
```

added functions for toggling the visibility:

```
showOptions = function (){
    $('.option').show();
}

hideOptions = function (){
    $('.option').hide();
}
```

and for the grand finale, added onfocus and onfocusout calling thoose functions

```
<input     type = "text" 
               id = "insertText" 
               autocomplete="off" 
               onkeyup = "if (event.keyCode == 13) {SearchAddress(option1.text)}
                          else {giveSuggestion()}" onfocus='showOptions()' onfocusout='hideOptions()'/>
```

Hope it's helpful

Comment: Very helpfull!

You think it is possible to do this without jQuery as well? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: possible but would be more complicated, I would suggest you using jquery. If you find it helpful please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: I will, once I got it working ;) And it is almost working, only: my options are not clickable anymore. You know why this is true?

Comment: Oh I see it's cause you are losing the focus from the input. therefore they are not visible anymore, i'll check it

Comment: Ok i got it, edited my answer with new jsfiddle, it was because onclick occured after onfocusout, so i changed it from onclick to onmousedown.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.option').forEach(function() { el.style.display = 'none'; })` is the "complicated" solution, what exactly makes this so complicated that you'd want to use the entire 30kb weight of jQuery for? [Support for `querySelectorAll` dates back to IE8](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll) as well so unless you **have to** support things most folks don't even call browsers anymore, **don't include jQuery** for toggling display I'd say...

Answer (score 7):

There is a standard way of doing that. HTML5 `<datalist>` tag! And the global browser support for it [74.5%](http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist). You may use the above fiddle as a fallback support. [Watch this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)

Comment: While your answer was very good, please, refraing from using w3schools as a source, developer.mozilla.org, html.spec.whatwg.org,  among others are much more reliable and updated. ([and please, read this link](http://www.w3fools.com/)). Upvoted anyway for good standard way of implement the datalist

Comment: @Bonatti while they could probably improve more, w3schools has some reasonably decent examples these days. They are sometimes explained in simpler terms than MDN (try reading up on prototypes on MDN and w3schools for example) I've found in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

If the **Data** is **stored in the database** for suggestion.

Then, after creating the `<input>` field Make use of `<datalist>` tag and place it inside a `<div>` container dynamically replace the content. Here is how you can do it.

```
<input type="text" name="search_email" list="listit" onkeyup="suggest(this.value)" id="search_email">
<div id="suggest_container" style="display:inline-block;">
    <datalist id="listit">
        <option ></option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Now  all you have to do is write Ajax code for it  like

```
function suggest(val){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('suggest_container').innerHTML=this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", ("dyn_suggest.php?value1="+ val), true); 
    xhttp.send();
}
```

After this just write the php code for it and check if the $_GET['value1'] is set or not. If not do nothing otherwise fetch the value

```
$count1=0; // for 5 values
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);

echo "<datalist id=\"listit\">";
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)!=0){
    while($i= mysqli_fetch_row($res)){
        $count1++;
        echo "<option value='".$i[0]."' >";
        if($count1==5){
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo "</datalist>";
```